Aliases in lerna
Is there a way to use alias names for packages in lerna monorepo?
Let me explain the requirement more precisely.
Assume below to be the directory structure.
Monorepo contains 3 packages and app package is dependent on pack-a and pack-b
# directory structure
monorepo/
 - package.json
 - packages/
    - pack-a/
       - src/
       - package.json
    - pack-b/
       - src/
       - package.json
    - app/
       - src/
       - package.json

# package json of app
{
  "name":"app",
  "dependencies":{
    "pack-a": "^1.0.0",
    "pack-b": "^1.0.0",
    "nanoid": "^1.1.1"
  }
}


When pulling packages from remote registry like npm, github etc, I can create alias name for package as below by mentioning it in package.json
"custom_package_name": "npm:nanoid@^1.1.1"

This way, in entire codebase, i can now use custom_package_name instead of nanoid. This works fine.
But similar aliasing is not working for internal packages of lerna monorepo.
I tried to replace  "pack-b": "^1.0.0" with "package-b": "npm:pack-b@^1.0.0"
I tried to do aliasing just like I did for external package and ran lerna run build but it failed.
